# Standard ways of revoking user access to a site

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I'm in the process of building a .NET MVC website where a requirement is that admin users should be able to lock accounts to not only prevent future log-ins but to also immediately revoke access to the site for a given authenticated user.

Locking the account is easy, but is there an established method of preventing access immediately in this type of scenario. Is it a case of checking on each request whether the requester's account is locked in the db and then clearing the authentication cookie if required?

I'd appreciate any pointers anyone has.

Comment: Clearing the cookie isn't even necessary as long as you check in the db if the cookie is valid.

Comment: Thanks. So would you check if the cookie is valid - by storing it server side as well or simply check the user record for the locked status and forget about the cookie?

Comment: The cookie should consist of a random 128 bit value stored in its own table. That way you can revoke it by deleting it, and a user can have multiple sessions at the same time. Alternatively you can look at whatever session support is built into ASP.NET.

Comment: Clearing the cookie isn't required if all content is witin a container which checks for authorization to view the content before content is even displayed.

Answer (score 1):

A method that I have used is to allow Admins to effectively assign discontinued users to a role marking those users as such.  The role can be called whatever you like, such as "Disabled", while active users would be assigned to a role of "Active".

Then I just prevent access via the Authorize annotation at the Controller(s) level:

`[Authorize(Roles = "Active")]`

Comment: What is the role those discontinued users are assigned to? "Discontinued"?  If you clarify that, your answer will be more useful.

Comment: @logc Thanks for the feedback. I added more details to the answer.